# Mostar datos de una base de datos en una tabla

Tags: java, netbeans

```
 void mostrarClientes() {

    DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
    modelo.addColumn("Identificacion");
    modelo.addColumn("Nombre");
    modelo.addColumn("Telefono");
    modelo.addColumn("Tipo de Pago");
    modelo.addColumn("Direccion");
    modelo.addColumn("E-mail");

    tblRegistroClientes.setModel(modelo);

    String sql = "select cli_identificacion,cli_nombre,cli_direccion,cli_tipo_pago,cli_telefono,cli_e_mail from cliente";

    String personas[] = new String[6];
    Statement st;
    try {
        st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            personas[0] = rs.getString(1);
            personas[1] = rs.getString(2);
            personas[2] = rs.getString(3);
            personas[3] = rs.getString(4);
            personas[4] = rs.getString(5);
            personas[5] = rs.getString(6);
            modelo.addRow(personas);
        }
        tblRegistroClientes.setModel(modelo);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FrmDiagAgregarClientes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Hola tengo el siguiente codigo, quiero poner datos que estan en mi base de datos a una tabla, pero no me salen los datos allí no me salen errores, simplemente no me muestra los datos.
Agradecería mucho la ayuda.

Comment: Nosotros no podemos ejecutar tu código. Utiliza el depurador para ver si el result set tiene algo o imprime si tamaño... Algo así

Comment: adjunta una captura de las exepciones que te salga en la consola, a simple vista no se puede hacer nada sin observar los errores